# How to get the dynamic values in SQL for while loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, ssms

In my scenario, I want to loop the query in SQL and need to update the details. I've a employee table named as `employees` and each employee having `empID` as primary key. I want to get the every employees' address info from the `empAddress` table which is having the empID as foreign Key. I want to update the ThumbID value as `newID()` to every employees. How can I do that using sql? I've tried something with while loop but don't know about getting the empID to update the address info. I've added my sample code which I've tried with that.

```
Select * from employees

declare @emp_id int,@i int,@dataCount int;

set @dataCount = @@ROWCOUNT
Set @i = 1

WHILE @dataCount >= @i
BEGIN
    print @i
    select @emp_id = empId from employees
    Update empAddress set thumbID = newID() where empId = @emp_id
    Set @i = @i+1 
END ;
```

Please guide me how can I get the `@emp_id` value as dynamic in SQL code? I don't have super knowledge in SQL. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use a `WHILE` loop at all? What's wrong with `UPDATE empAddress SET thumbID = NEWID();`? That query will update every row anyway, so why to it row by agonising row?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Do you want all addresses for the same employee to get the same `thumbId`, for instance?

Comment: SQL is a set based language.  Why the while loop?

Comment: @Larnu here I've mentioned the particular part of the functionality code. Actually we don't need 'WHILE'' for the normal update.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nope, the `employee` and `thumbId` will be different. Not the same value for the employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to update all the empAddress records where there's a corresponding employee record, right? You shouldn't need a loop for that:

```
UPDATE empAddress SET thumbID = NEWID()
FROM empAddress 
INNER JOIN employees ON employees.empID = empAddress.empID
```

Or, assuming every empAddress has an empID, just:

```
UPDATE empAddress SET thumbID = NEWID()
```

The looping way to do it in SQL would be to use a cursor, but watch how many people yell at me for even mentioning that cursors exist. (They're inefficient, but good to know about, IMO.) Here's an example that lets you call NEWID() once per employee ID, so all addresses for the same employee get the same unique identifier:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR   
SELECT empID, NEWID() FROM employees

DECLARE @currentEmpID INT
DECLARE @currentNewID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

OPEN cur  

FETCH NEXT FROM cur   
INTO @currentEmpID, @currentNewID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN       
    UPDATE empAddress 
    SET thumbID = @currentNewID
    WHERE empID = @currentEmpID

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur   
    INTO @currentEmpID, @currentNewID
END   
CLOSE cur;  
DEALLOCATE cur; 

empID   thumbID
1       FF358006-C41E-4632-BEB2-DF95E424B8CB
1       FF358006-C41E-4632-BEB2-DF95E424B8CB
2       DD19753C-1B4B-4D84-89F1-562DB4406A0F
2       DD19753C-1B4B-4D84-89F1-562DB4406A0F
```

Comment: The above answer helps me lot. Thanks a lot Max Szczurek. I've got the dynamic values in `while` loop. Once again, thanks much.